# Service starting every 5 seconds + AlarmManager automaticly stops and resumes

Tags: android

It's my very simple code:

Application:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public Intent myIntent;
public Button OnButton;
public Button OffButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    myIntent = new Intent(this, TimerService.class);

    OnButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.onbutton);
    OffButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.offbutton);

    OnButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            startService(myIntent);
        }   
    });

    OffButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            stopService(myIntent);
        }   
    });
   }
 }
```

Service:

```
public class TimerService extends Service 
{
public AlarmManager Alarmmgr;
public PendingIntent myPendingIntent;

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    Alarmmgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
}

public void SimpleMethod()
{
        //Here I will do something
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    SimpleMethod();

    myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Alarmmgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+5000, myPendingIntent);

    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    return null;
}


@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    Alarmmgr.cancel(myPendingIntent);
}

}
```

The problem is, that when I start my service and turn off the screen it is working for 30-50 minutes. After that time it stops for 10-50 minutes and resumes again... I want to run it continuously, without breaks. What I have to change in my code? I tried a timer but it doesn't work when I turned off the screen ;/.

Comment: Try making your service [foreground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'll need to prevent the phone from entering sleep mode?

Comment: Do you mean prevent from turning off my screen or something else? I wonder why other applications (not mine) can work in background and for example save files every 5 minutes. Maybe the interval is too small? Strange.

Comment: Added wakelock but still my service is sleeping sometimes ;/. I thought the service are always running in background, even when my phone is sleeping, but now I see that is dificult to get that effect...

Comment: Did you try setting a repeating alarm, instead of setting an alarm every time? It shouldn't change the behavior you're seeing, but who knows.